# How to write JSON schema for controllers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, jsonschema

Could anybody write examples of JSON schema for controllers
1) with CRUD actions
2) with custom actions

I have an api and I need to describe it with JSON schema, but I have no idea how to describe controllers.

My JSON schema for model

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/hyper-schema",
  "title": "Story",
  "description": "Story",
  "type": "object",
  "definitions": {
    "id": {
      "description": "Unique identifier",
      "type": "integer",
      "example": 1
    },
    "user": { "$ref": "#/definitions/user" },
    "title": {
      "description": "Title",
      "type": "string",
      "example": "Example Title"
    },
    "updated_at": {
      "description": "Updated date",
      "type": "string",
      "example": "Mon, 06 Mar 2017 11:07:34 UTC +00:00"
    },
    "created_at": {
      "description": "Created date",
      "type": "string",
      "example": "Mon, 06 Mar 2017 11:07:34 UTC +00:00"
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/id"
    },
    "user": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/user"
    },
    "title": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/title"
    },
    "updated_at": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/updated_at"
    },
    "created_at": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/created_at"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "id",
    "title",
    "user"
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "title": "Index",
      "description": "List of stories",
      "href": "/api/stories",
      "method": "GET",
      "rel": "index",
      "targetSchema": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": { "rel": "self" }
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "Show",
      "description": "Show story",
      "href": "/api/stories/:id",
      "method": "GET",
      "rel": "show",
      "schema": {
        "$ref": "#"
      },
      "targetSchema": {
        "$ref": "#"
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "Create",
      "description": "Create a story",
      "href": "/api/stories",
      "method": "POST",
      "rel": "create",
      "schema": {
        "properties": {
          "title": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/title"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "Update",
      "description": "Update a story",
      "href": "/api/stories/:id",
      "method": "PUT",
      "rel": "update",
      "schema": {
        "properties": {
          "title": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/title"
          }
        }
      },
      "targetSchema": {
        "$ref": "#"
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "Destroy",
      "description": "Destroy a story",
      "href": "/api/stories/:id",
      "method": "DELETE",
      "rel": "destroy",
      "schema": {
        "$ref": "#"
      },
      "targetSchema": {
        "$ref": "#"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, an API documentation tool seems to be what you are looking for, if so, check Swagger https://github.com/richhollis/swagger-docs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't describe a Rails Controller using JSON Hyper-Schema.  The concepts don't quite line up.  Links describe relationships between resources.  Sometimes those relationships refer to actions on the same controller, but sometimes they don't.  Based on what you have so far, you are looking at two schemas.  One schema to describe a story and another to describe a list of stories (index).  Although describing a controller doesn't make sense, I can help you understand how to describe links.

#Basics
Let's look at some of the keywords and describe how to use them.

##href
You've got the right idea here except that you are using the wrong URI Template syntax.  JSON Hyper-Schema uses the URI Template syntax described by [RFC 6570](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570) which is not compatible with the Rails syntax.  You will have to translate between the two.  For example, the `href` for your "Show" link would be.

```
{
  "href": "/api/stories/{id}"
}
```

##rel
`rel` describes how the resource relates to the resource being linked to.  For example, a story might have an `author` link relation that indicates a resource that describes the author of the story.

The tricky part is that relations can't be just any descriptive name you give it.  They must be either a value listed in the [IANA Link Relation registry](http://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml), the [JSON Hyper-Schema defined relations](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-luff-json-hyper-schema-00#section-5.2), or an absolute URI.

If the relation is defined in one of those two places, the relation should conform to the semantics they are documented to have.  If there are no existing relations that fit your needs, you need to use a URI instead of a string.  This URI can just be a unique identifier, but it is recommended that it link to documentation describing the semantics of the relation.

```
{
  "rel": "author"
}

{
  "rel": "http://example.com/relations/foo"
}
```

##schema
Think of one of these links as an HTML form.  The `schema` describes user input.  If `method` is `GET`, the input will be used to build a link with query parameters described by the `schema`.  If the `method` is `POST`, the input will be passed in the body of the request.  For example the following will build a link something like `/api/stories?page=1&perPage=10`.

```
{
  "rel": "instances",
  "href": "/api/stories",
  "method": "GET",
  "schema": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "page": { "type": "integer" },
      "perPage": { "type": "integer" }
    }
  }
}
```

##targetSchema
This keyword defines a schema that the result of the request should conform to.  I recommend that you don't use this keyword.  The response should be self descriptive.  You should not ever need this in order to interpret a response.  Just leave it out.

#Links
Now that we have the basics out of the way, here is how you would describe the links you have attempted so far.

##Index
This link might be given on the story schema.  I've included an example of some paging options.

```
{
  "title": "Index",
  "description": "List of stories",
  "rel": "instances",
  "href": "/api/stories",
  "method": "GET",
  "schema": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "page": { "type": "integer" },
      "perPage": { "type": "integer" }
    }
  }
}
```

##Show
This link would probably show up on the index schema showing how to retrieve a single story from a list of stories.

```
{
  "title": "Show",
  "description": "Show story",
  "rel": "http://example.com/relations/story",
  "href": "/api/stories/{id}"
}
```

Something like this might also show up on the story schema, but as a self link.

```
{
  "rel": "self",
  "href": "/api/stories/{id}"
}
```

##Create
This link might show up anywhere it makes sense in the flow of your api.

```
{
  "title": "Create",
  "description": "Create a story",
  "rel": "create",
  "href": "/api/stories",
  "method": "POST",
  "schema": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/title"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

##Update
This example assumes this link is on the story schema.  Because the `href` points to itself, it is unnecessary to define the `schema` keyword because the schema for the resource is already known.

```
{
  "title": "Update",
  "description": "Update a story",
  "rel": "edit",
  "href": "/api/stories/{id}",
  "method": "PUT"
}
```

##Destroy
This example assumes this link is on the story schema.  DELETE operations take no request body, so you should not include the `schema` keyword here.

```
{
  "title": "Destroy",
  "description": "Destroy a story",
  "rel": "http://example.com/relations/destroy",
  "href": "/api/stories/{id}",
  "method": "DELETE"
}
```